# $K_3(\mathbb{Z})$ and $\pi ^S_3$

Tags: homotopy-theory, kt.k-theory-and-homology, algebraic-k-theory

This is an afterthought on [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45376/z-48-and-moonshine-beyond-the-monster), and also on Gannon's book mentioned there, about $K_3(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/48$. Neither the question nor the book mentions a possible connection with the third stable homotopy group of spheres, $\pi ^S_3=\mathbb{Z}/24$. Does anyone know about such a connection?

Comment: There is a map of spectra $\mathbb{S}\to K(\mathbb{Z})$. I'm not completely sure, but I'd expect it to be injective on $\pi_3$.

Comment: @ Achim Krause: Could you explain where this map comes from (or give a reference)?

Comment: @abx It's just the unit of the ring structure. I think pretty much any book on algebraic K-theory constructs it, you can see [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/301780/entering-to-the-k-theory-realm/301797#301797) for a few references (I like a lot Mitchell's survey in that list)

Comment: One quick way of constructing it is as the map induced on K-theory by the exact functor of Waldhausen categories $\mathrm{Fin}_*\to\mathrm{Proj}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ sending $1_+$ to $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @Denis Nardin: Thanks a lot! Indeed Mitchell's paper completely answers my question. Sorry if it was too elementary, this is not my field.

Comment: @abx ah, but which is the image of index 2? Is there some cokernel with another interpretation?

Comment: The map to the cokernel of $\pi_3(S) \to K_3(\mathbb{Z})$ can be interpreted as the Hurewicz homomorphism to $H_3(K(\mathbb{Z})) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$, or as the Bökstedt trace map to $\pi_3 THH(\mathbb{Z})  \cong \mathbb{Z}/2$.  A key point in the 1976 paper by Lee and Szczarba is why the extension is nontrivial.  I use $\lambda$ to denote a generator of $K_3(\mathbb{Z})$ to refer to Lee (and Szczarba).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have $\pi_3(\mathbb{S}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/24\{ \nu\}$ and $\pi_3K(\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}/48\{ \lambda \}$. As Achim suggested, the unit map $\mathbb{S} \to K(\mathbb{Z})$ induces on $\pi_3$ the injection sending $\nu$ to $2\lambda$.

See the first paragraph of Section 2 of '[Divisibility of the Dirac magnetic monopole as a two-vector bundle over the three-sphere](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-13/22.pdf)' by Ausoni, Dundas, and Rognes.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Actually, this is already in the original paper of Lee and Szczarba where they prove $K_3(\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/48$ (Annals of Math. 104 (1976), 31-60.